# How to set the text of a UITextView from an array?

Tags: arrays, nsarray, uitextview, fact

I am trying to create a simple fact or joke app. It's simply not working. How do I get the UITextView to load a string, which is stored in an NSArray. Here is my code so far.

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"fact1",@"fact2",@"fact3",nil];
NSUInteger *count = 0;
textView.text = @"%@", [list objectAtIndex:count];
```

Comment: This is a very simple question and could easily be answered with some basic research

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
textView.text = [NSSTring stringwithFormat:"%@",[list objectAtIndex:0];
```

or

```
textView.text = [list objectAtIndex:count];
```

Comment: Do not use the 1st option. It is pointless and inefficient. Simply assign the string like in the 2nd option. Better yet, use the modern syntax: `textView.text = list[count];`.

Comment: The array already has a string. There is no need to format the string. So it is pointless to use `stringWithFormat:`.